# Most efficient method of querying MYSQL Table

Tags: python, mysql

So I have a table, which in the future will contain thousands of rows.

The rows contain date and other data which I need to return.

I will have an array of Dates which I need to query the original table with to return the appropriate data.

Currently I have a setup so that the whole original table is copied into a array, then for each date, I then use a for loop to copy all the data.

```
for un in range(0,listc)
    for i in range(0,bigtablec)
        if list[un] == bigtable[i][1]
            a[un] = bigtable[i][2]
```

So above is an example of how it currently works.

My question is whether using multiple SELECT queries on the bigtable will be quicker than the above method.

So for each of the "for un in range(0,listc)"  it will query the table with the corresponding date in the list array. Then the get the data from the single returned row.

Appologies if this is an obvious question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have appropriate indexes on the table, it will be faster to use a query to retrieve the desired data. The current implementation is an `O(n^2)` operation.  With appropriate indexes at the server, it will be either `O(log n)` or `O(n log n)` (I'm not completely sure I understand the logic shown in the loops of the OP).  In addition to the efficiency of using the indexes, it also means less data will be transferred from the server to the client application.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good solution.

You should try to bring all the data back in one network round trip rather than having one per date in the list.

You don't say how much data this represents in memory.  You'll want to be careful about "copy the whole table into an array".

The efficiency of the query is the combination of EXPLAIN PLAN, indexes on the table, and how many network round trips you need to bring it back.

Comment: My current table has 503 rows and 4 columns. Containing 1 index. Dateimte, then four float.  Takes up 64kb